Is there an easy way to convert a heredoc with variables into text with <?php echo ...?>?
I have a script with a long block like:
echo <<<EOF
html text containing a bunch of $variables
...
EOF;

It would be easier to make changes to this, such as making parts of it conditional, if it used syntax like
?>
html text containing a bunch of <?php echo $variables ?>
...
<?php

Is there any automated way in PhpStorm to convert the first syntax to the second?
I don't see anything like this in the intentions popup menu. You can change multi-line string literals into heredocs, but nothing to go this way.
I could do it with a regexp replacement, although this could have problems if there are any escaped dollar signs.

Just a hint but <?php echo $variables ?> is a long way of writing <?= $variables ?>

I know that, the distinction is irrelevant for this purpose.

About the regex way, since PhpStorm uses the JDK regex engine, you could easily know if a $ is escaped or not with a lookbehind like (?<!(?:^|[^\\])\\(?:\\\\){0,100})\$

Rector could be useful here: https://getrector.com/documentation/

@AkenRoberts I think one of our other devs here used rector when we upgraded to PHP 7 and 8, I didn't know it could do this.

It might not be able to out of the box, but you can create your own rector rules.
